# will display: table-cell be deprecated in future CSS?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

Does anyone know for sure if CSS display:table-cell will be deprecated in the future?

I need this advice for a project I am currently working on. If there is good evidence that it will be deprecated then I will avoid using it. Thanks.

I realize this comes close to an opinion question but thankful for any advice with references or suggestions.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the place for discussion.  Questions should be answerable - see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  You might be better off asking your question in a dedicated CSS forum or newsgroup.

Comment: "Since it's an opinion question" means it's usually wrong on Stackoverflow (except community-wiki threads and things like that, but i don't think this is a community-wiki candidate)

Comment: -1 Please ask only questions, don't try to start a discussion here. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @Andy etc. Ahh I see. I hadn't read that before. I guess I learned something. Is there a better place to post this question. I actually is more of an advice question than an opinion question, I need the advice because it's for a project that I am currently working on. If it's gonna be deprecated then I want to avoid using it.

Comment: @Josh: none than I know of, but I don't really trawl CSS forums and the like.  FWIW, `display:table-cell` only recently achieved compatibility across all major browsers.  CSS values are rarely deprecated, usually only if they are superseded by another value.  Also, if a value were deprecated, it would be unlikely to be actually removed for a long time as there would be a lot of websites using it that wouldn't get updated.

Comment: can someone give me one  more negative vote for this question so I can get points for deleting it at least? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the forseeable future. It’s in both CSS2.1 and CSS3 Tables (same functionality as CSS2.1), and has been interoperably implemented in all major current browsers.